# exchange server incoming mail issue from internet

Tags: exchange, smtp

I have registered a domain under godaddy.com, and I have exchange server 2010. My question is my exchange server can send and receive emails on the same network(local network). I can also be able to send emails to outside the network( to the internet), But I am not able to receive emails from outside the network(from the internet). I have opened the port 25 on my router and given IP address of Exchange server. My firewall didn't block port 25. Still I don't know why I am not receiving emails from the internet. I checked on GoDaddy DNS setting, A record, and MX record seems perfect. Can anybody help what is the reason of this ? can ISP blocks inbound SMTP connection? I can send emails outside network both via smart host and DNS MX record.

Comment: Give it time for your MX/DNS record change to propagate worldwide

Answer (score 0):

I don't suspect this to be a DNS caching issue.

In your case, this is a brand new MX record and A record so there shouldn't be any DNS caching involved.

What is probably the cause of the problem is that you haven't created an Accepted Domain and Recipient Policy in Exchange for the domain in question. I would look there as the root of your issue.

Answer (score -1):

You are likely to require a reverse DNS entry before anyone will trust your server to exchange emails with them. In addition, more mail servers are requiring encryption using TLS. Also some will require SPF and possibly DKIM.

Your DNS records will normally propagate within an hour or so but can take 48hrs to propagate worldwide.